# Using an external dll project to a c++/xll addin for Excel

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio-2010, add-in, xll

I have 2 VS projects in separate solutions. First one a dll, and the second one an xll trying to call a function from the first one. While it compiles without errors, Excel says

```
"The file you are trying to open, 'test.xll', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"
```

and if I press yes, I see a bunch of chinese-like letters. If I don't call the function from the dll project, then the xll works properly. What am I doing wrong? Using VS2010 and Excel 2010 x86.

The first one is a dll project

square.cpp

```
double _stdcall square (double &x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

square.h

```
 #pragma once

__declspec(dllexport) double _stdcall square (double &x);
```

The second project is an xll project

```
static AddIn xai_exp(
    "?xll_exp", XLL_DOUBLE XLL_DOUBLE,
    "XLL.EXP", "Number"
    );

double WINAPI xll_exp(double number) {
#pragma XLLEXPORT

    return square(number);
}
```

I also made a defFile for when I tested with VBA, but I don't think its needed here.

Comment: i'm facing the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: yes, but it was some time ago so I don't really remember how. If something comes to mind I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

The error you are describing shows up when a dll which is used by your xll is not found on the computer. So you have to make sure the dll is accessible to your xll.